# Is it possible to add virus to an encrypted file?

Tags: encryption, virus

If an attacker has physical access to your computer, could he modify an encrypted file as such that when you move the file to another computer and decrypt it there this new computer which you intended to use to safely decrypt your file will be infected?

I'm interested if this is possible for

LUKS / truecrypt

Veracrypt

PLAIN dm-crypt

which are all implemented in zuluCrypt.

If that is not the case would it be possible with encrypted *.odt files?

Answer (score 3):

For truecrypt and Veracrypt, I believe there is nothing stopping you from modifing the file and this is likely true for all FDE solutions.

However, it would be impossible to ensure the modified file decrypts into a virus, unless they somehow trick you into encrypting the virus with the same key or otherwise gain some additional knowledge.

It could be possible to embed the virus into the file non-encrypted and get it executed if there is some critical bug in your decryption software.